# Function overriding previous plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using the following code in order to store the graphs into a folder named `images`. Though it is working, the new image is overriding the previous image instead of generating a totally new plot.

```py
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pathlib
    import math

    def plot_graph(list_plot):   
      fig = plt.hist(list_plot, bins=15)    
      plt.title('analysis')
      plt.xlabel("Number one")
      plt.ylabel("Number two")
      # Create new directory
      output_dir = "images/"
      #mkdir_p(output_dir)
      #pathlib.Path(output_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
      plt.savefig('{}/graph{}.png'.format(output_dir, math.floor(len(list_plot)/10)))
```

Here `list_plot` is a list of numbers and I am calling the above function for every 10 iterations in my main program.

How can I get an image which can be a fresh image which does not override the previous image?

Answer (score 2):

`plt.close()` at the end of the loop should do it. Here you have [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html) about the function itself